# Html page will be displayed in four tv (screnn)

Tags: html, iframe, screen, web-parts

I have basic html page (w100% and h100%) and i need make a parts of html pages ( 4x 25%x25%). Becouse html page will be displayed in four tv.
Each tv would get its url to display a portion of the original htlm of the page

Any ideas how to do it? maybe iframe?

[example situation here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gydoC.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

Most desktop operating systems support four monitors in a 2x2 configuration used. So it might be enough to just open a single web browser, stretch it across the whole virtual desktop and show the single page inside it.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have several tv sets (1x1 tv, 2x1 tv, 4x1 tv) that run one application. So unfortunately I can not globally set up a view for everyone. I need to control the display by url.